# How do I get users information using javascript/jquery - session/cookies/etc

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on one web application, I dont have through idea about how to get users information like Session's data, cookies , and others..

I want to know :

- Is there any way ? and how ? to get above information and client side information using javascript/jquery.
- What are others client side data can i access using javascript/jquery.

Your suggestion(s) are welcome!!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean without user's consent?

Comment: BTW, you've asked 8 questions in a month and you haven't accepted any answer so far...

Comment: yes, it's with users' consent.

And thanks for your comment about "not accepted answers", i m here new..i diddnt knw the process, few mins i did that i.e. i hv accepted the answers for previous my posts....thanks again for this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading cookies from javascript is slightly trickier then it should be as it involves slicing up the long cookie string. It's still fairly trivial but I'd recommend you use an existing library to abstract these details away.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie if you're using jQuery or http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#script for vanilla